# What exactly are the resources used when querying a database and why do they need disposing?

Tags: c#, sql

When looking at the proper way to query a database in `C#`, I often see this advise:

> Make sure you dispose the Reader, Command, and Connection object

If I look at the documentation of [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx), [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), all what I can see as description for `Dispose` method is

> Releases all resources used by the Component.

I want to know what resources are used by these 3 types mentioned above. I thought only disposing `SqlConnection` will dispose and close other two nested objects(`SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`).

Also, there is many MSDN examples not disposing `SqlCommand` object. See
[this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, I have two main concerns here:

1. What precise resources are used for each type?
2. What are the consequences of not properly disposing each one of them?

I know that connection with database is unmanaged code and is not properly handled by garbage collector. I would like to know, what object or resources are used by each object and what will happen exactly if I don't dispose each one of them.

So PLEASE don't answer something general like unmanaged code, garbage collector, free resources...

Comment: *Also, there is many MSDN examples not disposing SqlCommand object.* > true, it is hard to write good documentation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sorry it didn't save so I wrote answer instead, but looks like it did actually save just didnt show up. I have deleted now

Comment: Real world example: if you don't properly dispose of your IDisposables, weird things start happening in your app that are difficult to explain and track down. That's why it's so important to be vigilant about it.

Comment: While it is interesting and probably good to know these things, I would claim that you don't actually need to know them. The fact that a class implements the `IDisposable` interface is a good enough reason to use it inside a `using` statement. It's one of the basic concepts of object oriented programming - Encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

1. This can change. The difference is they are unmanaged (think c instead of c#) and so we are basically just informing the unmanaged component it should release ANY resources it used... This includes closing open connections, freeing memory (as unmanaged code does not get the benefit of the garbage collector), closing handles it has requested from the operating system.
2. Memory leaks mostly. Half open connections on the database side. Failed code reviews and jibes from more experienced developers :P

Try read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to simply check the [source code these days](https://referencesource.microsoft.com). All the information you need is there. For example [SqlConnection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data) perfoms the following on dispose:

> ```
>   override protected void Dispose(bool disposing) {
>         if (disposing) { // release mananged objects
>
>             // V1.0, V1.1 did not reset the Connection, Parameters, CommandText, WebData 100524
>             //_parameters = null;
>             //_activeConnection = null;
>             //_statistics = null;
>             //CommandText = null;
>             _cachedMetaData = null;
>         }
>         // release unmanaged objects
>         base.Dispose(disposing);
>     }
> ```

[base.Dispose](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,5657bad357bf9d75) does this:

> ```
>   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
>         if (disposing) {
>             lock(this) {
>                 if (site != null && site.Container != null) {
>                     site.Container.Remove(this);
>                 }
>                 if (events != null) {
>                     EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)events[EventDisposed];
>                     if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

So cached meta data & event handlers among other things.

If a class implements `IDisposable` then there is a very good reason and you should probably use a `using` block.